# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: cannot assign to function call

Tags: javascript, uncaught-reference-error

I'm working on this snippet that calculates the cost of buying multiple items at a time. Every time the user buys 1 item, the price increases by 15%.

I'm getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: cannot assign to function call
when trying to display the total to the document.

Is it where I have converted the .toFixed() value to a number (function) so the sum is equal to a function value? How could I get around this?

```
function displayStore() {
// Testing on 1 item
const items = ['paw'];
// If not buying 1
if (game.storeMultiple !== 1) {
    for (let item in items) {
        // set p to initial price
        let p = storeItems[items[item]].cost;
        let sum = p;
        
        for (let n = 1; n < game.storeMultiple; n++) {
            // set p to new price
            p = Number((p * 1.15).toFixed(1));
            // add to sum
            sum += p;
        }
        console.log(`${items[item]}-cost`); // logs 'paw-cost'
        console.log(sum); // logs 203
        document.getElementById(`${items[item]}-cost`) = sum; // Uncaught ReferenceError: cannot assign to function call
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` is a function call and returns an html node, you can't assign something to it. Get the property you want to modify on the node (textContent or innerHTML, etc..) and assign you value to this.

Comment: Ugghg.... of course. Just one of those moments haha.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
document.getElementById(`${items[item]}-cost`) = sum;
```

with

```
document.getElementById(`${items[item]}-cost`).textContent = sum;
```

You cannot assign something to what a function call returns; **you can only *assign* to variables and object properties.**

---

Not related, but also wrong:

Replace

```
for (let item in items)
```

which is meant to be used to iterate over own properties of an object, with

```
for (let item of items)
```

which is meant to iterate over an array (which is what you are trying).

Comment: Great thanks for the extra info :)